# Winforms can't set Property-Values at design-time

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

Iam trying to create a own GridControl based on a DevExpress Grid (v.14.2). This seems to work well, but my Settings-Object isn't editable in Designer.

This is my Grid so far:

```
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    [DXToolboxItem(true)]
    public class MyGrid : GridControl
    {
        private Settings _settings;

        public MyGrid()
        {
            _settings= new Settings();
        }

        [Category("My Category")]
        [Description("My Description")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public Settings Settings
        {
            get { return _settings; }
            set { _settings = value; }
        }
}
```

And this is my Settings-Class:

```
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public class Einstellungen
    {
        [Category("My Category")]
        [Description("My Description")]
        public bool CanGroup { get; set; }

        [Category("My Category")]
        [Description("My Description")]
        public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any Attribute which iam missing? Searched on msdn but they also just recommend the used attributes...

In the Designer i just can see:
**Settings | MyNamespace.Settings** but no way to edit the bool Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this works...

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public class Einstellungen
{
    [Category("My Category")]
    [Description("My Description")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public bool CanGroup { get; set; }

    [Category("My Category")]
    [Description("My Description")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) The TypeConverter did it.